# Threading-Pool Error in .Net Invalid cross-thread operation

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading

today i get one Exception while I am trying to do a Thread Pool in a Backgroundworker that target a  Listbox, does someone can help me´:)

```
    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    Me.Status_Gathering = True

    ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(Me.ThreadCount.Value, Me.ThreadCount.Value)
    ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(Me.ThreadCount.Value, Me.ThreadCount.Value)
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = Me.ThreadCount.Value
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
    For Each state As String In TextBox1.Lines
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf ScrapProxy, state)
    Next
End Sub
```

This is the Sub which i target:

```
    Private Sub ScrapProxy()
    Dim webClient As WebClient = New WebClient()
    Dim list As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
    Try
        For Each text As String In Me.TextBox1.Lines
            Dim input As String = webClient.DownloadString(text)
            Me.CSP = text
            Dim matchCollection As MatchCollection = REGEX.Matches(input)
            For Each obj As Object In matchCollection
                Dim match As Match = CType(obj, Match)
                TextBox2.AppendText(match.ToString & Environment.NewLine)
                Me.ProxyAmount = Convert.ToInt32(Me.LB_GatheredProxies.Items.Count)
            Next
            Dim flag As Boolean = Not Me.LB_Logs.Items.Contains(text)
            If flag Then
                Me.ListBox1.Items.Add("[+]Scraped: " + text)
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.ListBox1.Items.Add("[-]Dead Link: " + Me.CSP) **Here i get the exception :c**
    End Try
End Sub
```

Does someone can help with Delegates or something?
Best regards kashed

Comment: You can pass the array of strings to the `RunWorkerAsync()` method overload that accepts an `object` argument: it will be the `DoWorkEventArgs.Argument` in `DoWork()`. -- Don't even think about Invoking() the UI Thread from a BackGroundWorker. Pass (Locking) the Results to `[BackgroundWorker].ReportProgress` (setting `BackgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true`) -- This is all much easier handled using a `List(Of Task)`. BTW, no idea why you (and others, actually), set `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True` when you're not handling this kind of response at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop at this line:

```
For Each state As String In TextBox1.Lines
```

You can't access GUI elements in a thread different from the main GUI thread. And that is called in a different thread, you can tell by the function name: `BackgroundWorker1_DoWork`.

You need to either `Invoke` your code and make it painfully slow, or ditch the background worker from .Net 1 and write correct, modern code using `await`/`async`.